# Accessing application.conf on play module configuration

Tags: java, playframework, guice

I'm trying to configure a database client instance using Guice to create an AbstractModule, but i can't access application.conf using dependency injection, since the injector is not created yet.

Here is my code

```
@Singleton
public class DatastoreModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Inject
    private Config config;

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(
                config.getString("mongodb.host"),
                config.getInt("mongodb.port")
        );

        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

        Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(
                mongo,
                config.getString("mongodb.databaseName")
        );

        bind(Datastore.class).toInstance(datastore);
    }
}
```

How can i access the configuration without using the deprecated Play.configuration API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it in the constructor (in Scala). Here is the example from my project

```
class Guard(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule{
```

In Java it is the same:

```
public class DatastoreModule extends AbstractModule {

  private final Environment environment;
  private final Config config;

  public DatastoreModule(Environment environment, Config config) {
    this.environment = environment;
    this.config = config;
  }

  ...

}
```

More details: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Configurable-bindings

Just do not overuse it:

> In most cases, if you need to access Config when you create a component, you should inject the Config object into the component itself or into the component’s Provider. Then you can read the Config when you create the component. You usually don’t need to read Config when you create the bindings for the component.

I very very rarely use it. It is always almost better to inject the configuration into component itself.

Comment: So what is the best way to initialize a service such as a database client? The most logical way for me was to create an instance and directly bind it, but I'm still not familiar with the DI concepts, so I'll be glad to understand the best practices.

Comment: You just initialize it as a singleton and do all settings in the singleton. You can look into an open source project. For example this one: 
https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo/tree/master/app/uk/co/panaxiom/playjongo

Simple binding to class: https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo/blob/master/app/uk/co/panaxiom/playjongo/JongoModule.java

Then do all stuff in the bound singleton: 

https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo/blob/master/app/uk/co/panaxiom/playjongo/PlayJongo.java

Comment: The example I gave with a configuration in a guice module (not recommended way) is from the PAC4J integration in play. This is a complicated project with a lot of settings and also with the support of many platforms. So the authors stick with it's own vision of configuration and architecture that must fit into a lot of different frameworks: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j